# How real enumerator for collection is implemented?

Tags: c#, list, ienumerator

There is an example how enumerator **migh** be implemented:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ienumerator.aspx and this is a valid approach. However real `List` or `Array` invalidate their iterators when they are modified.

And my question is -- how is it done?

The best I can think of is still keeping the reference to the collection, and also some stamp (int id). Every time the collection is resized, the stamp is incremented. And on every `moveNext` at enumerator side, the stamp is checked -- when there is a match, enumeration continues, if not -- exception is thrown.

But this is just my wild guess, I didn't find anything solid.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> how is it done?

Trivial. Keep a version counter. Compare version counter when the enumerator was created to the one currently in the enumerated object on every yield. Finished. Obviously: change version on every change.

Now, "i didn't find anything solid" - did it ever occur to you to - ah - read the source code? It is all public, you know...

http://referencesource.microsoft.com/

you look for mscorlib.

FOr example, ArrayList: http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/arraylist.cs

It does not get more solid than that.

Comment: Heck Yeah! Of course you can use one of the following tools Reflector/IlSpy/Resharper to look at the actual code from the actual version of .NET (or 3rd party library) you are using.

Comment: I will accept your answer in 10 minutes (limitation of SO), thank you already :-) I forgot MS went open-source, so, yes, it is solid :-D